# Running VBA on AWS

Tags: excel, vba, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-lambda

I am totally a novice when it comes to cloud computing. I want to run a VBA code that performs some calculations and excel operations on an excel file . I want to deploy this code in AWS server and run this VBA code on 600+ excel files located across 4 different local machines. Is this even feasible? I couldn't find anything meaningful(or maybe I did but did not understand) clue towards solving this problem.
Please help me .

Comment: Are you saying that you want to run a VBA script inside of AWS but you want it to process Excel spreadsheets that themselves are located on 4 machines local to your network (not in the cloud)? Why do you want to do it this way? What's the value of running the VBA script in AWS?

Comment: I don't know . I thought it would require a cloud to run the code simultaneously on all 4 machines? I need to run the VBA code on all machines together and generate 600+ reports. Pardon me if cloud doesn't make sense. I am not that technical. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I’m not saying that cloud is not appropriate. I’m asking you what value you hope to achieve. There is a service called AWS Batch that might be helpful, but first I think you need to solve “how do I process one XLS file”, which might involve you uploading the XLS to Amazon S3, launching EC2, processing the XLS, writing the result back to S3, and distributing the updated file wherever it needs to go. Generally speaking, to use AWS services, you’re going to want to push the data (the XLS files) into AWS (probably S3) first.

Comment: I am okay with inserting excel files into AWS as long as it is able to process multiple excel files quickly.  Perhaps, I need to write an additional code to run these files on loop. I just don't want the users to manually paste the codes into the VBA editor of their excel files and run them individually.

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not expose a VBA lib. However, if you are interested in .NET development, you should use the **AWS SDK for .NET.** You can find examples in the Github repo located here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/dotnet3.5

If you want to manipulate Excel files, look at using a .NET Excel lib. Then you can write logic on the cloud that uses the .NET lib. Purhaps write a Lambda function.